# Data access from view hanging

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a snowflake view which can be queried using the browser.

However when the same query is queried using C# code it hangs.

```
using (var connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString";

                connection.Open(); // Works

                var sqlQuery = "select \"Col1\", \"Col2\", \"Col3\", \"Col3\", \"Col5\", \"Col6\" from \"View1\";
                var command = new SnowflakeDbCommand(connection);
                command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                command.CommandTimeout = 240;
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // Works
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows) // Works and is true
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) // Hangs here
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

The connection string contains the account, user, password, db, schema, role and host.

The View contains around 25000 entries.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you might have a complex query that takes a lot of time to process

Comment: Yeah can I see the sqlQuery? Or try running a simple get date query.

Comment: Also I have never used this DB but looking at the Sql Command Class example from Microsoft, they skip the if statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Comment: Also try setting command.CommandType to something other than the default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

So hanging can be caused by multiple reasons. I cannot tell you what goes wrong without logging. Here is the README and the last section has an example of how to enable logging. https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/README.md

Without reading logs, I can only guess the cause of hanging. One guess is that you don't have access to S3. When result set is large (which is 25000 entries in your case) Snowflake server will write result set to S3/Azure Blob and client will download result from S3/Azure Blob. If your network does not have the access to S3/Azure Blob, then it will hang.

But again, this is just pure guess. To the exact reason, your best bet is enable logging to see what is going on.